# Merging two array of columns into 1 array columns in hive

Tags: pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I would like to merge two array based columns into 1 single output column with pipe delimiter, maintaining the array list in the output. Is it possible to achieve it in hive or spark sql?
Please note in the output that wanted to achieve with pipe delim.

Input:

```
id  val         ph
1   [123,456]   [789,987]
```

Output:

```
id  Comb_col
1   [[123,456]|[789,987]]
```

Comment: So, your result is desired to have the schema, array(array(int, int)) with delimiter `|`? no.

Comment: Hi Lamanus, Yes, i am looking for array(array(int,int)) with "|"(pipe) delimiter

Comment: As I said, the array delimiter is always `,`, AFAIK. Your statement should be then string

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, CONCAT('[', val, '|', ph, ']') as Comb_col
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want use Hive, you can do it like this:

```sql
from
  (
    from
      your_table -- Change this with your table name
    select
      transform(id, val, ph) using '/bin/cat' as (id, val, ph)
  ) t
select
  cast(id as int) as id, -- Assuming that your id column is int.
  concat('[', val, '|', ph, ']') as comb_col;
```